# Thermal printers

Tags: api, networking, thermal-printer

Apologies if this is posted in the wrong place. I’m really struggling to find a thermal printer that connects directly to the internet.

I’m looking for a service that sends api calls over the net to a thermal printer. Does this exist?

For now I’m trying to avoid Bluetooth capability.

Comment: It is indeed the wrong place. We only cover questions about writing software, and even when otherwise software-development-specific, requests for product, library, or other recommendations are explicitly off topic.

Comment: That said, building your own print server is typically $5-$10 if going the Raspberry Pi route (the bottom end 0W being quite sufficient), so I wouldn't suggest feeling all that constrained by vendor support.

Comment: As a result, many printers support Ethernet interfaces. Communication is possible by connecting to TCP/IP port 9100. Did you make a mistake or overlook something?